# Excel: Scanning column with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I just started off as a new programmer and I'm trying to create Vba code to scan the following data in Excel.

Let's assume

```
Apple = 123456

Apple Juice = 987654

Pear = 234567
Pear Juice = 987654

Orange = 345678

Orange Juice = 987654
```

The codes for each item will be given but what I want is to write a program to detect the specific codes and assigning it the names (apple, apple juice etc.). If "123456" appears first, then the cell below it will be assigned "Apple Juice". If "234567" appears first, then it will be assigned "Pear Juice". It is challenging for me as Juice category shares the same "987654" unlike the Fruits which has a unique FruitNo assigned to it.

However, I am having difficulty writing the codes for the scanning of above cells. I have tried using the ActiveCellOffset but it doesn't seem to be functioning to the way I want it.

[The following codes are what I have tried so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsaT8.png)

[And this is the outcome I would like to have. The red letters are the names that the program is suppose to come up with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzqZ4.png)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you provide a snap shot of your sheet and also the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi zac, Ive edited the post and added the snaps in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your code from

```
If FruitNo = 987654 And ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0) = 123456 Then
```

to

```
If FruitNo = 987654 And Range("A" & i).Offset(-1, 0) = 123456 Then
```

should solve your issue (and same for another `IF` condition). However, this can be achieved using formula also.

Comment: Hi Mrig, it worked perfectly for me and thank you very much. If I may, is it possible to tweak the code such that it doesn't only scan the cell above it but instead, scan let's say 5 cells above it, but without specifying in the codes to scan 5 cells above it?

Comment: @Benjamin - It's hard to make out how your data will be so a screen shot ofrsample data will be helpful.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. It's not necessary to tweak the code anymore. Thank you!